# How to ignore spaces in maxLength property of textFormField?

Tags: forms, dart, flutter

Spaces are also counted when considering maxLength, I want to avoid the trailing and leading spaces and then apply the property.

Comment: You can feed the image without the spaces by doing `str.trim()`

Comment: I have done that but I want to use the maxLength property so that user can't type more characters

Comment: Why don't you wanna consider white spaces in maxLengh if you don't wanna let user insert more characters? I do not get it. I mean, if I don't count them then, maybe is because they are trimmed out, but if they are part, for example, of a password field with a maximum length, then they must be counted in the password length. Btw, did you consider using the `onChanged` event of the TextField?

Comment: I am considering cases when user inserted some spaces by mistake at starting or in the end or while pasting data from somewhere. At the same time, I want to put a limit on the number of characters. I think I should be able to put a check using onChanged - Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: In onChanged() you can replace the spaces or you can notify user to remove the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use `TextFormField`, use `TextField` with an `onChanged` function

```
onChanged: (val) => _myLengthCheck(),
```

that then sets a:

```
decoration: new InputDecoration(
  errorText: _someError,
),
```

with `_someError` being set or unset in `_myLengthCheck`

Answer (score 2):

If white spaces might not be counted, you can simply inhibit its input.

The below example don't let user input whitespaces by using the built in input format `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` and a RegExp:

```
TextFormField(
                validator: _validateInput,
                inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
                    new RegExp(r"\s\b|\b\s")
                )],
                maxLength: 12,
                controller: _textController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Input your bonus code'),
              ))
```